# Similarity of Trapezoid error?

Tags: geometry

Unfortunately I am doing this with my phone, so bear with me. Thanks.

On a contest test there was this question of trapezoid similarity:
Given the trapezoid shown where $AD$ || $EF$ || $BC$, find $EF$.

The trapezoid $ABCD$ has A on the bottom left corner and the remaining points go clockwise with $BC$ parallel to $AD$. Point $E$ is on $AB$ such that $EB=4$ and $AE=6$. Point $F$ is on $CD$ such that $CF=5$ and $FD=7.5$, $BC=9$, and $AD=13.5$

I thought this problem would be a simple proportion with my answer as $EF=13.5$, but that is $AD$. I really wish I could elaborate on my work, but I have another competition in 20 minutes. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Let $O$ be the intersection between $AB$ and $CD$. Then triangles $AOD$ and $BOC$ are similar. So $$\frac{AO}{AD}=\frac{AB+OB}{AD}=\frac{OB}{BC}$$From here you get $OB=20$. You already noted that $EF$ is parallel to $BC$, so the triangle $EOF$ is similar to the first two.$$\frac{EO}{EF}=\frac{EB+BO}{EF}=\frac{OB}{BC}$$ This yields $EF=24*9/20=10.8$

Answer (score 0):

The following figure depicts the data given:

[image]

We have

$$x+y+9=13.5\ \text{ and } \ 100-x^2=156.25-y^2$$

or

$$x=4.5-y \ \text{ and } \ x^2-y^2=-56.25.$$

Substituting        $x$ we get

$$y=\frac{76.5}{9} \ \text{ and } \ x=-4.$$

So, our trapezoid looks more like this one below

[image]

We have here some similar triangles. From the two on the right we get that $a=3.4.$ And from the two on the left we get that $i=1.6$

So, $$EF=a+9-i=10.8.$$